# Changing Jekyll's source directory and keeping other directorys there they are

Tags: jekyll

I would like to change Jekyll's source directory but in the same moment I would like to keep the other relevant directorys like `_includes` at the same place.

To achive this I set `source` in `_config.yml` to `_source`. This works but it seems that all other configuration values like `includes_dir` are always relative to `source`.

**How can I configure** `includes_dir` **and all the other values independently of** `source`**?**

My desired directory structure looks like this:

```
+- _source
+- _includes
+- _posts
+- ...
 \ _config.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jekyll expects all directorys below the source directory.

I found that out by looking into [Jekyll's source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll). The class `Site` contains several methods dealing with the configured directorys. All of them use the method `in_source_dir` to determine the effective path.

The method `configure_include_paths` is a good example for this.

```
def configure_include_paths
  @includes_load_paths = Array(in_source_dir(config["includes_dir"].to_s))
  @includes_load_paths << theme.includes_path if theme&.includes_path
end
```